# How to merge two Spreadsheets into one in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

There are two Spreadsheets namely main and secondary. Main has 3 sheets in it and Secondary has 1 sheet under it. For simplicity I'll show modified version of them both under

Main spreadsheet

```
Name Qrating Brating Crating
A       8       5      4
B       5       2      1
C       6       7      9
```

Secondary spreadsheet includes personal details of same people present in Main spreadsheet as seen below.

```
Name Age Rank qualified
A    23   2      yes
B    45   22     yes
C    44   23     yes
```

I have looked up ways to merge and combine but all seem to be ways in combining data vertically, but what i want is all the data in secondary to be added in Main file in accordance to the name. I don't seem to find the solution online where data is filled horizontally after tallying a common column between two files. if anyone can give solution or guide me to a direction that would be very helpful. Thankyou.
end result should be like this when merged

```
Name Qrating Brating Crating
A       8       5      4
B       5       2      1
C       6       7      9

Name Age Rank qualified
A    23   2      yes
B    45   22     yes
C    44   23     yes

Name Age Rank qualified Qrating Brating Crating
A    23   2      yes       8       5      4
B    45   22     yes       5       2      1
C    44   23     yes       6       7      9
```

Comment: Is this not the right place for this question? If so please do guide me where to post. I am seeing negative vote on this and wondered. Would appreciate it as I am seeking any help on this query. Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheets, visually indicating the expected outcome?

Comment: Hi there, sorry I just saw your reply, The outcome would have been merging the above two tables with Name column as the common factor between them. I am currently using Merge app for this. This works for me. On another note, would you have an idea as to what possible reason could have been for the downvote on this question? Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand this. As I said before, can you provide a copy of the spreadsheets (or at least screenshots), so that the outcome is clarified? About the downvote, I **guess** (based on the closing vote) that's because the question needs more focus (you didn't provide any formula you're working on, so you're not asking for a modification of the current formula but for a formula written from scratch).

Comment: I have added the sample output above, The idea was to find the common name in both sheets and then merge both the data referencing the same name together, in the above example you can see with name as common denominator, other columns from both sheet were merged. Apologies as I cannot post real data or its screenshot as it is private data of company I am freelanced from.  Also that could have been a possible reason for downvote but this requirement of mine is easily doable with click on features than formula in Microsoft excel which is what I expected as answer but  my bad for not mentioning.

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for? Using a Google Drive Script, using a Python wrapper for the Google Sheets API, using google cloud API, etc. ?

Comment: Okay, I sense something is wrong here, I found the solution with the add-on in google sheets. But I feel people are getting confused because I am now sensing this platform is for code related help rather than click on tool solutions. I was looking for either actually, but code was my last option as I was thinking from MS Excel's internal option point of view. If that is the case I will delete this question or move it to appropriate place

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to do this with click on feature in Microsoft Excel, I was expecting the same in Google sheet but it seems the add-ons help for this as I didn't find any tool in sheets itself. There are many add-ons to achieve this, I am using Merge Sheets add on for this.

Comment: In Google Sheet it is far more easy to do it with a single formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge multiple sheets form different spreadsheets like this

```
=query({
IMPORTRANGE("ID_1"; "SheetX!A2:E");
IMPORTRANGE("ID_2"; "SheetX!A2:E");
IMPORTRANGE("ID_3"; "SheetX!A2:E")
};"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")
```

and then adapt query as you need. Wait for an example from your side. Sincerely yours.